# How To Merge User Main Photo in Image?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, gd, facebook-php-sdk

Hello facebook developers can any one help me a quick summary how can user photo merge in background image which i provided?

I already try the text and its working.

EDIT:

Hello Here Is Some Code I Got: where $name is " name of the user" i made it correct.

```
       $canvas = imagecreatefromjpeg ("bg.jpg");      
       $black = imagecolorallocate( $canvas, 61, 61, 61 );
       $font = "font.ttf";
       imagettftext( $canvas, 15, -1, 51, 60, $black, $font, $name );

       imagejpeg( $canvas, "img/".$fbid.".jpg", 50 );
       ImageDestroy( $canvas );
```

and now my problem is how to include the photo of the user in the background?

Comment: Your question is not really helpful. Have you tried something before? Can you post some Code?

Comment: @Stony i added some codes i got without merging picture of user... can you help me...

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, you'll need to make use of ImageMagick for PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php.

```
$img1 = new Imagick( "YOUR_BACKGROUND.png" );
$img2 = new Imagick( "FB_IMAGE.png" );

$img1->compositeImage( $img2, imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0 );

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $img1;

?>
```

Good luck!